# SSIS Data Flow: Aggregate Task 'hides' my other columns downstream

Tags: visual-studio, ssis

I'm hoping someone can help me with this.

I have an SSIS package that updates a table, and one of it's columns is a 'current average'. In my Data Flow Task, I need to look at 'tickets sold' for each record, aggregate the average, and add it as part of my insert.

Problem is, that Aggregate Task hides all my other columns. I've got 'tickets' and 'avg tickets', 'venue' and 'time'. When I go to put in the record to my DB Destination, all 3 source columns (venue, time, tickets) aren't visible, and the only one available is my aggregate. I need all four for my insert. How do I get those other columns to 'pass through' the aggregate task so I can use them?

Source: Excel sheet

```
Venue, Tickets Sold, Show Time
Royal Oak Music Theatre, 300, 7:00 PM
Saint Andrew's Hall, 200, 9:00 PM
Fox Music Theatre, 700, 8:00 PM
```

Destination: SQL Table

```
Venue, Tickets Sold, Show Time, Average Tickets Sold Per Show
Royal Oak Music Theatre, 300, 7:00PM, 300
Saint Andrews Halls, 200, 9:00PM, 250
Fox Music Theatre, 700, 8:00PM, 400
```

Comment: I'm dense - can you help me understand what the "current average" would be for your data? Perhaps a few rows of sample data from the source and then what you expect it to be for the destination?

Comment: Yeah, absolutely! I didn't have these things handy - I've had to abstract the question to keep things private. Let me edit original post.

Comment: Okay, I edited my original post. Ultimately what I'm trying to do is calculate an average inside the ssis package, and all the things I've found self-searching say use an aggregate task - but my source columns disappear downstream of the aggregate task and I don't know why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given your sample data, it appears you're creating a running average. Each row in adds a new weight to be factored into the average.

The challenge is, the Aggregate component in SSIS doesn't do that. It's going to give you an average by each grouping (or none, in your case).

You're going to need a Script Component to compute this.

Check the "Tickets Sold" column as an input for the script (which will likely be named TicketsSold or Tickets_Sold or some permutation there of)

You'll need to define a new column in your Output Buffer I'll assume is named `runningAverage` and it's type is dt_numeric,

I'm free handing this code so syntax errors are mine but the logic is sound ;)

```
public class ScriptMain : SomeComponent
{
    int itemCount;
    int total;

    /// initialize members
    public override void PreExecute()
    {
       this.itemCount = 0;
       this.total = 0;
    }

    /// Process all the rows, one at a time
    public override void Input0_ProcessInputRow(Input0Buffer Row)
    {
        // accumulate
        this.itemCount++;
        this.total += Row.TicketsSold;

        // populate the new column
        // force the floating point division lest we truncate with integer division
        Row.runningAverage = this.total / (this.itemCount * 1.0);
    }

}
```